# Is that possible to block incoming call in android using react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react native app i want to block/unblock all incoming calls for certain time. when triggered a certain function.

I have searched on google many times but didn’t get any satisfactory answer/result.

Expecting any dependencies or code for call blocking functionality.

Comment: Hi Did you find out any solution or way to achieve this functionality, if yes please share with me

Answer (score 2):

I searched for you and I found this component :

```
npm i react-native-nope-call-block-native-code
```

you can use this. If u help, you can write or [read docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nope-call-block-native-code)

Answer (score 0):

Getting started
$ npm install react-native-nope-call-block-native-code --save

Mostly automatic installation
$ react-native link react-native-nope-call-block-native-code

Manual installation
iOS
In XCode, in the project navigator, right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]
Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-nope-call-block-native-code and add RNNopeCallBlockNativeCode.xcodeproj
In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libRNNopeCallBlockNativeCode.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries
Run your project (Cmd+R)<
Android
Open up android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainActivity.java
Add import com.reactlibrary.RNNopeCallBlockNativeCodePackage; to the imports at the top of the file
Add new RNNopeCallBlockNativeCodePackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method
Append the following lines to android/settings.gradle:
include ':react-native-nope-call-block-native-code'
project(':react-native-nope-call-block-native-code').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,  '../node_modules/react-native-nope-call-block-native-code/android')
Insert the following lines inside the dependencies block in android/app/build.gradle:
compile project(':react-native-nope-call-block-native-code')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).